# Hsqldb driver being randomly null

Tags: java, persistence, hsqldb

I am involved in writing a project which requires servlet->database connection. I am collaborating with another person who have designed a database using HyperSQL (hsqldb), I am now trying to merge my project with his by adding his code to mine.

Further to my issue though. When I copy the code, it works, usually. I have few methods that use the data from the database and compare them with user input.

When attempting to connect to the database, I would randomly succeed or fail, getting the following error ;

`Unable to acquire a connection from driver [null]`

I of course initialise a driver ;
`Class.forName("org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver").newInstance();`

Now, when running my method, it sometimes succeeds, and sometimes fails, here is the XML file for the DB;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- 
Creates both the HyperSQL databases using hibernate. No password or username is set.
-->
<persistence version="1.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="monsters" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <class>databaseManagement.Monster</class>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver"/>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value=""/>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value=""/>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:hsqldb:monsters"/>
      <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect"/>
      <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
  <persistence-unit name="users" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <class>databaseManagement.User</class>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver"/>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value=""/>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value=""/>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:hsqldb:users"/>
      <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect"/>
      <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably an attempt is made to open the database in a readonly directory.

1. You need to specify a username for both persistence units. The default username is "SA".
2. The file path of the database that you specify in the URL is relative. It resolves to the execution directory. As you are developing a web application, you need to specify a directory that can be written to.

One way of doing this is by including a variable in the path, such as "jdbc:hsqldb:file:{$directorypath}/monsters" where the directorypath is the name of the web application's data dirctory, as specified in your web.xml file.

Comment: Password and username are intentionally left blank - I could've added that the original application works just fine. It is also meant to save to local.